# Make a program ignore a number

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that determines whether or not a number is odd or even with appropriate labels to say what the total is, and a counter but I need help trying to make the program ignore 0 because when you enter that in the program, it's meant to finish but also counts it as an even number and adds it to the EvenCount, thank-you!

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Num, Decider, Oddcount, Oddtotal, Evencount, Eventotal As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Do
        Num = InputBox("Please enter whole number")
        Decider = Num Mod 2
        If Decider > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Odd")
            Oddcount += 1
            Oddtotal += Num
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Even")
            Evencount += 1
            Eventotal += Num
        End If

    Loop Until Num = 0
    LabelOdd.Text = Oddtotal
    LabelEven.Text = Eventotal
    LabelEvenCount.Text = Evencount
    LabelOddCount.Text = Oddcount
End Sub End Class
```

Comment: on your else condition but an if (Num!=0) statement

Comment: If you know how to use the if statement what's the problem?

Comment: wrap your current if statement into another one asking **if( Num !=0)**

Comment: This really is as simple as checking the value of Num with an `If` statement. You've already demonstrated that you know how to check the value of a variable with `If Decider > 0 Then` so what's stopping you employing a similar method and checking the value of `Num`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore zero, you should better use a Do..While statement, which evaluate the condition before stepping into the loop.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim Num, Decider, Oddcount, Oddtotal, Evencount, Eventotal As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Num = 1 ' Initialised to force in step into loop
  Do While Num <> 0
        Num = InputBox("Please enter whole number")

       ' Recheck the value inserted - if zero, break.
       If Num = 0 Then  Exit While 

        Decider = Num Mod 2
        If Decider > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Odd")
            Oddcount += 1
            Oddtotal += Num
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Even")
            Evencount += 1
            Eventotal += Num
        End If
  Loop

  LabelOdd.Text = Oddtotal
  LabelEven.Text = Eventotal
  LabelEvenCount.Text = Evencount
  LabelOddCount.Text = Oddcount
End Sub End Class
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem so I have no idea why it's the accepted answer. The value of `Num` is set _after_ the `Do While` statement is evaluated so if the user's input is 0 then the value of `Evencount` will still be incremented erroneously.

Comment: You're right, missed a line. Thanks for pointing it out. Answer updated accordingly.